# MudBlazor RowEditCancel Action, call a Task

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

In the MudBlazor documentation for MudTable, it shows that there is a function named RowEditCancel that says the following.

The method is called when the edition of the item has been canceled in inline editing.

In an example in the documentation it calls a method like this.

```
RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues"

private void ResetItemToOriginalValues(object publisher)
{
    ((Publisher)publisher).Id = publisherBeforeEdit.Id;
    ((Publisher)publisher).Name = publisherBeforeEdit.Name;
    ((Publisher)publisher).Url = publisherBeforeEdit.Url;
}
```

I have my own method that I'd like to call, but not sure how to call it instead.  Here's my method, how do I call it?

```
private async Task CancelEditing()
{
    editingPublisher = new Publisher();
    await PublisherService.GetAdminPublishers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RowEditCancel` is an `Action<object>` type delegate. It expects a method that returns no value and receives an object type argument.

Change your method return type from Task to void and add an object type argument to it.

### Example:

```
private async void CancelEditing(object element)
{
    editingPublisher = new Publisher();
    await PublisherService.GetAdminPublishers();
}
```

### A few handy references:

https://mudblazor.com/api/table#properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0